# Map (key value ) compare with table columns data

Tags: java, database, hashmap

I have CSV data as below:

Key 1 = value 1, Key 2 = value 2, Key 3 = value 3, Key 4 = value 4, Key 5 = value 5, Key 6 = value 6

I have table with below columns:

Col1(key1) = value 1, Col4(Key 4) = value 4, Col5(Key 5) = value 5

I need to check if the columns in CSV are there in TABLE and has same data

```
public List<Map<String, String>> parse(Path csvPath) throws IOException {
    Reader in = new FileReader(csvPath.toFile());

    Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT
            .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
            .withIgnoreEmptyLines(true)
            .withDelimiter(',')
            .withTrim()
            .parse(in);


    return StreamSupport
                    .stream(records.spliterator(), false)
                    .filter(csvRecord -> Integer.parseInt(csvRecord.get("Col 4"))>0)
                    .map(csvRecord -> csvRecord.toMap().entrySet().stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                    e -> e.getKey(),
                                    e -> e.getValue()
                            )))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

//TABLE DATA//

```
          public int CassandraConn(){
                         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          String cqlStatement = "select * from table_name;
          for (Row row : session.execute(cqlStatement)) {
              System.out.println(row.toString());
          }
          }
```

Comment: Is there an unique identifier (`Primary Key`) for each row in the file and table?

Comment: yes there is one column which name project id which is present in both csv and databse table and has unique data